# Regex to match a word in CSV

Tags: java, regex

How to a match word in comma separated values (CSV) string with a single space after each comma.

Let's say:

```
String = 'abc, def, ghijk, l, mn, opqr, stu';
```

What would be the regex to match a complete word in the above string?

Edit:
lets say i want to match ghijk from the given string.

Comment: Which word?. Sample input and output is mandatory..

Comment: Check for basics of reg ex in java http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: You can use `String[] tokens = string.split(", *");` to get all the words.

Comment: `I want to a word` What's the verb? Replace? Match? Eat?

Comment: "*What would be the regex to **match** a complete word*" — So I guess that's "match", @zx81.

Comment: @zx81 - EAT?? .. lol "P

Comment: To match `ghijk` as column use this regex: `(?<= )ghijk(?=,)`

Comment: @anubhava Avoid answering in Comments... :)

Answer (score 3):

To match all words followed by a comma and **exactly** one space:

```
\b\w+(?=$|,[ ](?![ ]))
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hU8oK8)

To retrieve the matches:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+(?=$|,[ ](?![ ]))");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(your_original_string);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
// matched text: regexMatcher.group()
}
```

Comment: Do you really need `(?![ ])` in your regex?

Comment: @anubhava Yes: he said followed by `a single space after each comma` See demo, two spaces and more must fail. :)

Comment: Your demo is not matching last word in the record.

Comment: You're welcome but I still think OP would just need `String[] tokens = string.split(", *");` to get all columns.

Comment: @anubhava You're probably right... We can only guess, I jumped on `single space` but probably didn't need to. Always guessing the asker's intentions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the pattern: `(\S*?)(?=,)` means: anything that is not a whitespace (lazy evaluation) and which is followed by a comma:

```
String aaa = "abc, def, ghijk, l, mn, opqr, stu";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S*)(?=,)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(aaa);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
abc
def
ghijk
l
mn
opqr
```

Comment: That also matches words that are followed by a comma and two spaces.

Comment: @zx81 right, which is exactly what he was asking for according to his description + examples.

Comment: His description says followed by `a single space after each comma`. Two spaces after the comma must fail.

Comment: @zx81 I know but I assume that he doesn't want to include "extra whitespace" in a word as he also wrote: "to match a complete word"

Comment: That's cool, it's totally up to you, I was just pointing it out since he said `single space`. Wording is sometimes imprecise and it may be that you made the right guess. We're always guessing the asker's intentions, your guess is as good as mine. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali you're right, it's a habit from another flavor of regex to apply laziness.

Comment: But what you have can be easily achieved using `String[] tokens = string.split(", *");`

Comment: @anubhava you're totally right - but the OP asked for a solution that uses regex.

Comment: Yes and `", *"` is also a regex as `String#split` works on regex only.

Comment: @anubhava but you can also do: `str.split(", ")` which will work just fine without a regex though you can argue that ", " is a regex as well :P

Answer (score 0):

Another REGEX.. :)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "abc, def, ghijk, l, mn, opqr, stu";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(?=,\\s+?)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            // m.find();
            // System.out.println(m.groupCount());
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group());
            }

        }
O/P :
abc
def
ghijk
l
mn
opqr
```

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess, because your question is unclear:

```
String[] words = csv.split(", *");
```